# Using Python in EventGhost

Tags: python

i have a script to play a random wav file from a folder works good but Il like it to only play between 9am and 5pm not sure how to do that
Thanks

```
from os.path import isfile, join
import random

#path you want to get wav files from
path = "C:\Windows\Media"
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f)) ]

onlywavfiles = []
for f in onlyfiles:
    if f[-3:] == "wav":
        onlywavfiles.append(f)

#generate random number based on number of available files
randomnum = random.randint(0,len(onlywavfiles)-1)

eg.plugins.System.PlaySound(path + "/" + onlywavfiles[randomnum], 1, False)
```

Comment: Use the windows task scheduler to run your script instead

Comment: What's the issue with your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not say what triggers that script, I' ll have to guess.

I guess: The script is triggered by an event from your home automation. Perhaps someone rings the bell, or Balto requests his meal, or a fish jumps out of the aquarium.

That triggers an event and starts the script. The script plays a random wav file from the Media folder.

But you don't want the music to be played outside the interval you specified.

It doesn't matter, if the script is still executed/triggered, only the sound must not be played.

You could simply read the time, extract the hour and test 9 < hour or hour > 16
and return from the script before the sound is played if the test is true.
(I'm from Germany so we have 24 hour time. I dont know how python returns hours for 12 hr systems.)

```
from os.path import isfile, join
import random
import datetime

hr = datetime.datetime.now().hour

if hr < 9 or hr > 16: 
  exit()

#path you want to get wav files from
path = "C:\Windows\Media"
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f)) ]

onlywavfiles = []
for f in onlyfiles:
    if f[-3:] == "wav":
        onlywavfiles.append(f)

#generate random number based on number of available files
randomnum = random.randint(0,len(onlywavfiles)-1)

eg.plugins.System.PlaySound(path + "/" + onlywavfiles[randomnum], 1, False)
```